# Error during installation of Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint, mbr, gpt

I have installed kali and Linux mint together and then I decided to install Windows 10 on my 2nd HDD. I made a bootable USB with ventoy. When I try to install, it says Windows can't be installed on drive with MBR partition table. I disconnected my Linux HDD now on 3rd HDD same error is happening!

Can anyone tell me why it's happening? Is there anything wrong with bootable USB? How can I fix this?

I'm not expert in such technical problems. It's my first time to try this.

Comment: Did you format the disk as GPT? Is Secure Boot enabled in the BIOS? What is your computer model?

Comment: The problem is always in the target drive, not the others. Disconnecting was/is a waste of time. This is what you need ton understand: (Unlike Linux) Windows strictly requires GPT for the proper UEFI mode that SHOULD be used for any UEFI based computer (all since ~2012) and conversely MBR for BIOS machines or Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode in UEFI.

Comment: @harrymc This has nothing to do with Secure Boot. And of course they din't. The drive is MBR, hence the error message when the installer has been booted, normally, in UEFI mode.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: The mode he's booting in and the disk format has everything to do with it. See your own answer.

Comment: IIRC Windows refuses to boot at all without secure boot, which MBR is incompatible with. At least in recent versions. Given that OP seems to be using a fresh install, I presume it's recent enough to have this enforced. But yea, question screams BIOS/UEFI issue

Comment: @harrymc *The mode he's booting in and the disk format has everything to do with it.* Yes, that's exactly what I said. And still Secure Boot has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @harrymc It's as simple as this: You commented asking for info/clarification and that included 3 question. One is relevant, other is arguably not - computer model - but it doesn't hurt to ask and people asking for help should provide it anyway. So far so good. The question about Secure Boot is totally irrelevant and I merely mentioned it. Knowing that you should've either ignore me like you do to anyone, usually, remove the comment and re-post it requesting only relevant to the problem information or clarify your own request for clarification. (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily prepare the drive where you intend to install Windows from any of the Linux based OSes you already have.

You can do the same from within the Windows installer itself but it requires familiarity with command-line only tools.

Assuming you'll take the easier route, start by connecting all the drives again. Then boot Linux (Mint is preferable because Kali is for experts ONLY and experts wouldn't be here asking this sort of questions) and open GParted (install it if not already).

In GParted make sure to select the target drive for Windows from the top right dropdown menu and then Devcies menu > Create new partition table > Select "GPT". Apply/confirm. Done!

Additional notes:

- First and foremost you probably shouldn't be using Kali for obvious reasons and knowing to you don't need it then making a triple-boot is too much of an hassle for no good reason whatsoever.
- If the above seems just slightly too complicated, don't do it. Use one or more Virtual Machines instead. Unless you need intensive graphical hardware access in Windows, running it a VM makes no significant difference.
- Whenever installing any OS, standalone or multi-boot but especially when doing the latter, you must familiarize yourself with your specific firmware (UEFI or the old BIOS). Namely you need to be able to confidently adjust certain settings that may be required for certain OSes and, of course, be able to confidently select the boot order / OS selection to manage any dual- or multi-boot configuration.
- Understand any OS' requirements. Namely ion this case and as already commented: *Windows strictly requires GPT for the proper UEFI mode that SHOULD be used for any UEFI based computer (all since ~2012) and conversely MBR for BIOS machines or Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode in UEFI.* Also understand that any Linux distro should also be installed in UEFI mode and that when multi-booting ALL OS must be installed in the same mode. The only exceptions are a few niche and obscure Linux distros that aren't for normal usages as Deskto Linux anyway.
- Secure Boot has no bearing here but you need to know how to enable/disable it even if only to troubleshoot. ALWAYS prefer Secure Boot ON unless told otherwise or only for troubleshooting. All mainstream Linux distros support Secure Boot and always did sibnce more than a decade ago. Windows 11 requires Secure Boot among other hardware characteristics and firmware settings.

Comment: Whaqt you were/are trying to do has nothing to do with Kali. Take care.

Comment: Yep anyways thanks again brother

Comment: If the answer was useful consider accepting it.

Comment: Can you just tell if the usb partition is in mbr then can windows be installed through it or its also be in gpt for using as bootable device

Comment: GPT or MBR are requirements for the drive where you'll be installing Windows. It's irrelevant in the installation media. Now, the reason you're asking is because you're trying Rufus to make the media, is it? There's nothing wrong with that but it has options that potentially confuse many people. Prefer the official Media Creation Tool directly from Microsoft's download page. Or use the multi-boot tool Ventoy to take advantage of higher capacity drives. Just install it from any OS and then simply copy as many ISOs it can take, Windows an Linux and other, (...)

Comment: (...)  pretty much anything that can be booted by Grub will work. Ventoy is just a special Grub that chainloads drive images (ISO files). It boots with a familiar Grub menu listing everything you copied in the previous step, just select what you want and it'll boot the installer or live/installer like it would with a single OS.

Comment: Yes yes thats correct I've been using rufus and ventoy from your answer its cleared my doubt before i thought thats there is problem in usb while making it bootable. Can i have your telegram or any other way to interact because you're helping i will ask only when there will no way to get solution otherwise won't disturb you bro some words can't say here on public platform

Comment: To be clear: The Rufus dev and I don't see eye to eye (we've add several discussions here and elsewhere). While he's adamant it always works regardless of the settings, I often recommend GPT/UEFI